# Scilab 3d Plot Datatips

Tags: scatter-plot, scilab, datatip

I am plotting some data in Scilab as 3d-Scatter plot (Scilab 6).
With the datatip toggle it is able to show some information about each data point: x,y,z value.
I am actually plotting node-values, x,y are the coordinates, z is the damage.
Is it possible to change the output of the datatip? I would like to display a node-label instead of the coordinates using the datatip-function!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `datatipSetDisplay` (cf. examples in [help page](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/datatipSetDisplay.html))

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it works fine when I create the datatips with datatipCreate(...) and change the representation afterwards. But is there a way to change the text of the datatips generally - so if I use the datatip-toggle in the figure window the new text including x,y,z and a label is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom diplay function per "PolyLine" object in your plot, e.g.

```
t=0:0.1:10;y=sin(t);
function s=mydatatip(h),s="DATATIP",end
plot(t,y)
datatipSetDisplay(gca().children(1).children(1),mydatatip)
```

Please note, here `gca().children(1).children(1)` is a handle to the "PolyLine" object of the plot.